# localhost; contentEditable; security

Tags: localhost, security, contenteditable

I am using my localhost hosted site to make blog entries and so forth directly in contentEditable divs. onload or reload IP address is read and if 127.0.0.1, an event is added to allow the revised content to be saved. This is very convenient but I wonder if I am heading for some security breaches.

What think?

Answer (score 0):

Dont trust client-side code for security since it can be altered.

Comment: I agree but in this case it only acquires code (the save function) when it is loaded from localhost ... but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: But wouldnt a malicious use be able to enable\call the save function anyways?

Comment: Well the contenteditable divs are ordinarily eventless; an onmousedown event is only added if I open it from the localhost as: ip = getIp();
 if(ip === "127.0.0.1"){
  d.firstChild.onmousedown = function(){ saveNote(this);};
 }

Comment: Again, a malicious use would run the script manually, gaining the ability to call the saveNote method

Comment: OK then I will make contentEditable conditional as well ... if(ip === "127.0.0.1"){ d.contentEditable = true ... ???